# Plot with a reference line and shaded / colored region

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

How can I add horizontal reference lines at 4 and 6 (y-axis) and shading below each reference line on the following plot?

```
Plot[i, {i, 1, 10}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) for reference.

Use `{}` to define multiple functions to be plotted and `Filling` for the shading.

```
Plot[{i, 4, 6}, {i, 0, 10}, Filling -> {3 -> {2}, 2 -> Bottom}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution via [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) and graphic primitive `Rectangle[]`

```
Plot[{i, 4, 6}, {i, 0, 10}, 
     Epilog -> {Opacity[0.3], Lighter@Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 4}], 
                Lighter@Blue, Rectangle[{0, 4}, {10, 6}]}]
```

[image]