# How to find the Bottom

Tags: plotting

While I was thinking about [Plot with a reference line and shaded / colored region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120836/plot-with-a-reference-line-and-shaded-colored-region), I came up with

```
Plot[{i, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {i, 0, 10}, 
Filling -> {5 -> {4}, 4 -> {3}, 3 -> {2}, 2 -> Bottom}]
```

[image]

as an easy solution strategy directly from the help instructions.

One can try with `Table` to virtually automate the `Filling` Stuff, but will fail miserably on `n -> Bottom`

```
Table[n -> {n - 1}, {n, 3, 5, 1}]
```

> {3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}, 5 -> {4}}

```
Plot[{i, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {i, 0, 10}, 
Filling -> Table[n -> {n - 1}, {n, 3, 5, 1}]]
```

[image]

So, how to add `n -> Bottom` to a `Table` ?

Comment: Does it have to be part of the table? And you can't add another plotline?

Comment: i.e. `Plot[{i, 0, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {i, 0, 10}, 
 Filling -> Table[n -> {n - 1}, {n, 3, 6, 1}]]` is no good?

Comment: What's wrong with simply adding an `If`? `Table[n -> If[n == 2, Bottom, {n - 1}], {n, 2, 5, 1}]`? Don't try to make a complex problem out of a simple one.

Comment: @Feyre go ahead and answer!

Comment: @IstvánZachar go ahead and answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I decide to automate a special kind of plot, I try to produce something that can handle more than the particular special case I have at hand. For this question, I think the following makes a good start.

```
SetAttributes[myPlot, HoldAll]
myPlot[expr_, hlines : {__}, domain_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{n, fills, plt},
    n = Length[hlines] - 1;
    fills =
      Append[If[n == 0, {}, Table[i -> {i - 1}, {i, 3, n + 2}]], 2 -> Bottom];
    plt = Prepend[Sort[hlines], expr];
    Plot[Evaluate @ plt, domain,
      Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts, Filling -> fills}, Options[Plot]]]]
```

Of course, it handles the example given in the question.

```
myPlot[x, {4, 6, 8, 10}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: plot1]

#### Other tests

Only on horizontal line.

```
myPlot[x, {5}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: plot2]

Horizontal lines not ordered.

```
myPlot[x, {10, 4, 8, 6}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: plot1]

Can accept plot options.

```
myPlot[8 Abs[Sin[x]], {4, 8, 6}, {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Black}]
```

[image: plot3]

#### Note

I say this is the just start of a full implementation because there are argument patterns that `Plot` handles that `myPlot` won't. For example, suppose you wanted to plot several expressions as well a list of horizontals. As coded above, `myPlot` handles that badly. It would not be all that hard to add support for multiple-expression plots, but my point is that adding support for multiple expressions is only one of many features that might need to be added to make `myPlot` really robot.

Comment: Nice, but I'd like to see the primary plot line above the horizontals. +1 of course.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I would like that too. Certainly one of the many but important details that needs to be considered when fooling with `Plot`. I could make the excuse that I was only preserving the way OP handled layering, but that would be a cop-out -- I simply missed that particular detail.

Answer (score 7):

```
Plot[{i, 0, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {i, 0, 10}, Filling -> Table[n -> {n - 1}, {n, 3, 6, 1}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{i, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {i, 0, 10}, 
 Filling -> 
  Flatten[{Table[n -> {n - 1}, {n, 3, 6, 1}], {2 -> Bottom}}]]
```

or

```
Plot[{i, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {i, 0, 10}, 
 Filling -> Table[n -> {n - 1}, {n, 2, 6, 1}] /. {1} -> Bottom // 
  Evaluate]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Table` as in your question but add `2-> Bottom` to the list.

```
Join[Table[n -> {n - 1}, {n, 3, 5, 1}], {2 -> Bottom}]

(* {3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}, 5 -> {4}, 2 -> Bottom} *)

Plot[{i, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {i, 0, 10}, 
 Filling -> Join[Table[n -> {n - 1}, {n, 3, 5, 1}], {2 -> Bottom}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]